# How can I present the postgres errors in a nice way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I am new to Ruby on Rails, and this is my first project. I don't known really much, but I have a table that it has an unique index. For example, for User, the unique index is the e-mail, so I cannot add two users with the same e-mail.

However, I would like to know how can I catch these databases errors, and how can I present it in a nice user message?

Now, I just got a database error.

Comment: Welcome to [so].  Could you provide some information as to what you are currently doing, and what you have done to attempt to solve the issue?  Also, just a hint: you might want to validate and check over the information provided before attempting to write to the database.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, the relation is between three tables. Student (id, name, email), Class (id, subject, teacher_id... ), and student_class(student_id, class_id).

Student_class has an unique index - student_id, class_id

For Student and Class, I did what Jakob S suggests below, but I don't know how I can do Student_Class. I have the migration for student_class, and I create an unique index for it there.

Comment: @KarlaSilva, if you have further questions than the one you've asked here, feel free to create a new question and don't forget to include the relevant code for us to better help you out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The Rails way (not the book)

The Rails way to do that is to validate the data before it even reaches the database. This is done using [validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).

In your specific case you're looking for [`validates_uniqueness_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of), which could be used like

```
class YourModel
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
end
```

This is good enough for making sure the unique constraint isn't triggered in most cases.

#### Catching the database errors

Now, if you really want to capture database errors, it is indeed possible, but perhaps not optimally so.

If you create your own `save` method, we can add the option to catch the database exceptions before they bubble up to the controller:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def save(*args)
    super
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
    errors[:base] << :taken
    false
  end
end
```

The `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` is the exception ActiveRecord raises when a unique constraint is violated. With this, we get the following:

```
>> u = User.new(:name => "Bob")
=> #<User id: nil, name: "Bob", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> u.save
=> false
>> u.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007faa06569458 @base=#<User id: nil, name: "Bob", created_at: "2013-10-10 07:59:02", updated_at: "2013-10-10 07:59:02">, @messages={:base=>[:taken]}>
```

This works and my preliminary testing didn't find anything obviously broken, so it might actually be a viable solution. One caveat though, is how validations will clobber the `errors` array:

```
>> u.valid?
=> true
>> u.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007faa065a5368 @base=#<User id: nil, name: "Bob", created_at: "2013-10-10 08:08:36", updated_at: "2013-10-10 08:08:36">, @messages={}>
```

Comment: +1, but it would be interesting to know how to handle that PG error and raise it as a rails validation error all the same.

Comment: Agreed, so I investigated and have updated my answer with a way of doing exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Rails default validation like

```
 class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true # you can give multiple field name like  validates :name,:email ..
  validates :name, uniqueness: true
 end

  >> p = Person.new
  #=> #<Person id: nil, name: nil>
  p.errors.messages
  #=> {}

  >> p.valid?
  #=> false
  >> p.errors.messages
  #=> {name:["can't be blank"]}

  >> p = Person.create
  #=> #<Person id: nil, name: nil>
  >> p.errors.messages
  #=> {name:["can't be blank"]}

  >> p.save
  #=> false

  >> p.save!
  #=> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name can't be blank

  >> Person.create!
 #=> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name can't be blank
```

More infomation Please go through this link [click Here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).

Comment: Link-only answers generally aren't appreciated. Please add some explanation.

Comment: ok,next time i will follow that.Thanks